# SQLITE Query For Composite Data to show in one column for the identical column value

Tags: database, sqlite

I have to implement one complex Query in SQLITE but as don't have much proficient knowledge in SQLITE.

I have One Table named as PupilTestAnswers in which i have composite primary Key

My Schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE PupilTestAnswers (
  testQuestionId integer NOT NULL,
  pupilId integer NOT NULL,
  testId integer NOT NULL,
  score integer NOT NULL DEFAULT(-2),
  lastUpdated text,
  isMyScore integer NOT NULL,
  isUploaded integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(testQuestionId, pupilId)
);
```

now what i my data look a like is as follows:
[image]

Now What Data I want is that it will give me list of Data By  this should be the unique Combination in result.

e.g.

```
18 |   3 | 2 | 1 | 2016-01-06T06:13:50.000Z | 1 | 0
16 | 154 | 2 | 0 | 2016-01-06T06:13:50.000Z | 0 | 0
```

for above tow row as `their LastUpdate values are same for the same testId` so i need only one row in result as follows for this row and those rows testId and Last Update are different then I need separate row for them

```
18,16 | 3,154 | 2 | 1,0 | 2016-01-06T06:13:50.000Z | 1,0 | 0,0
```

So aboe thing i want to achieve in SQLITE .

I have tried this in SQLServer but I can't convert the query in SQLITE.

I have following SQL Server Query that giving me what I want

```
;WITH CTE 
as(
SELECT
    *, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY testid, lastupdated) RN 
FROM PupilTestAnswers
)
SELECT DISTINCT RN,R.testId, R.lastupdated, R.testname,
(STUFF((SELECT ','+cast(pupilId as varchar(10)) FROM CTE  WHERE CTE.RN=R.RN FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) PupilId,
(STUFF((SELECT ','+Name  FROM CTE  WHERE CTE.RN= R.RN FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) Name
FROM CTE R
```

I have included some inner join also to get testname and pupil name in another column from its id

Comment: Why are you keeping the SQL Server query a secret?

Comment: @CL. please check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

To get one output row for each unique combination of `testId` and `lastUpdated`, use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ...
FROM PupilTestAnswers
GROUP BY testId, lastUpdated;
```

(This works in any SQL database.)

To combine the values of multiple rows from the group, use the [group_concat function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT group_concat(testQuestionId),
       group_concat(pupilId),
       testId,
       group_concat(score),
       lastUpdated,
       group_concat(isMyScore),
       group_concat(isUploaded)
FROM PupilTestAnswers
GROUP BY testId, lastUpdated;
```